# Zend Framework 2 - fastest Cache Adapter?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-cache

My Site will rely heavily on caching so which Chache Adapter should i go for?
Filesystem will surely be the slowest, but which of these are the fastest?
I have control over my php extensions so i could probably get all of them to work except the Zend Server ones.
Are there any benchmarks to all these Adapters?

```
Apc Adapter,
Dba Adapter,
Memcached Adapter,
Memory Adapter,
WinCache Adapter
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be good advised to read WHAT those caches actually do.

- [Apc](http://php.net/manual/de/book.apc.php), [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/de/book.memcached.php) and Memory are pretty much memory based cache systems.
- [DBA](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php), to my understanding, is like a DB on Filesystem
- [WinCache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.wincache.php) is an all around solution heavily optimized for, you guess it, Windows.

Caches all have their advantages and disadvantages. To my PERSONAL experience, APC probably always outpaces memcached. So my vote would head towards APC

While this is an old article, i still feel it is quite a nice read: [PHP Performance Series: Cachin Techniques](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/02/27/php-performance-series-caching-techniques/)

As far as your benchmarking question is concerned: do it yourself! While global opinions might help you to choose the final produkt, it doesn't really take that much time to see which one is fastest. They are called adapters for a reason and with ZF2 most often all you need to do is to change the adapter and everything will still work ;)